# Django rest framework complex return info for a single api

Tags: django, rest

How to return complex information in a single api under Django rest framework? 
Assuming I have a model:

```
class Apple(models.Model):
    color
    size
    shape
```

With a single api: /api/get-apples, I want to return a json like below:

```
{"red": {"round":[0.1,0.2,0.3],"spigold":[0.3,0.4,0.5]},
"yellow":{"round":[0.1,0.2,0.4],"spigold":[0.2,0.4,0.5]}}
```

What will be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by  complex return by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd edit my previous answer but I think it is a good example of using serializers with covering view,urls and serializer parts. Therefore, I didn't want to delete it :)

Here is how to return a complex json structure.
As I mentioned before, as far as I know, we can't do something like that by using rest framework's serializers class because it need comparison and grouping. I'll use rest_framework's api_view structure.

Also, I didn't understand types of size and shape in your model and what is your desired output. Therefore, this might be wrong but you'll get the idea anyway.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_apples(request):
    # define your queryset here as you want.
    basket = Apple.objects.all()
    data = {}  # empty dictionary
    for apple in basket:
        if data.get(apple.color, None) is not None:  # if same color of apple exists in basket
            # check if shape exists or not.
            if data.get(apple.color).get(apple.shape, None) is not None:
                data.get(apple.color).get(apple.shape).append(apple.size)
            else:
                data.get(apple.color)[apple.shape] = [apple.size]
        else:
            data[apple.color] = {apple.shape: [apple.size]}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

I didn't test this code but probably this will work. Let me know if this works or not!

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not the exact same code. I have to modified it for my actual need, but the idea of this works perfectly in my scenario, I guess the only thing missing is to add an import "from django.http import HttpResponse". if you want it to be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Uhhh yes I forgot to add it. I'll add it now and mark this as answer if this worked so that others who have similar problem with you can use this.

Comment: How scalable is it?

Comment: @KishorPawar It isn't. It has to check every item on the queryset. But this is an exceptional case. Normally, you just pass the queryset to the serializer. Here, he wanted to have an advantage on the client side, therefore it is a disadvantage on the backend side.

Answer (score 1):

Create a serializers.py in your app's folder and add this code into it.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class AppleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Apple
          fields = ('color', 'size', 'shape',)
```

In your views.py:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .serializers import AppleSerializer

class get_apples(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AppleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
    # Here create your queryset.
        queryset = Apple.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

In your urls.py:

```
url(r'^api/get_apples/', views.get_apples.as_view(), name='get_apples'),
```

And you are good to go.
Output will be like this.

Let's say you have 2 apples.

```
{{"color": "red", "size": "blabla", "shape": "round"},{...(another apple json)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, to better explain my question, is how to aggregate the apple jsons together by some criteria? For example I have data: {red, round,0.1},{red, round,0.2},{red, spigold,0.1}. And I want the api output to be {red: {round: [0.1,0.2], spigold:[0.1]}}.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that with rest framework. If you want,  you can create your output by yourself by checking every object and creating lists yourself. If  you want to do it yourself,  it's pretty easy and I can help you.

Comment: Also I wonder why do you want that?  Of course that'd decrease the size of the return json but you have to make more comparison to achieve this. Therefore, you have to calculate well before deciding what to do.

Comment: Because the final deliver of data will need the aggregation. The consideration of doing this is to reduce the frontend's calculation by put the calculation to server side. Because I'm creating a small app that only a very limited number of users will use it. Do you know how to do it by myself? Much thanks!

Comment: Well played. I just want you to be sure of what you want.  I'll help you when I get home.